# How can i login to Ajax form with scrappy python

Tags: python, scrapy

I can login into the website where i get the login URL like

`www.abc.com/login.html`

Now in all the modern websites there is no page like login.html but when i click on login , then a popup appears with the login form.

i am not able to find out how i can login into that form with scrappy

Comment: use selenium, but i guess you already know that based on your previous question.

Comment: See if you can fake the login request or use an existing login cookies.